# Time out/Retry in chat room

Tags: discussion, bug, chat

Everytime when I chat with SO user, I will get time out issue. This require me to click the retry to resend my message.

I hit this issue quite a long time. Am I the only one who facing this? I have checked my network, it working.

Comment: What is the exact error you get if you open the dev console of your browser and look at the failed request?

Comment: It happens to me sometimes, when my connection is misbehaving. It's something on your side. Another factor is VPN, when connected to company VPN you're behind their firewalls and security software, which might slow down the connection.

Comment: @rene I will look on it once it failed again

Comment: It might also help if you can reveal what your local and network setup looks like. Basically the thing @sha mentioned. We've seen cases where a single anti-virus product or browser plugin turned out to be the culprit.

Comment: @rene yes, or just a funky ISP that keep changing IP address very frequently (to the point of different IP every request) or ISP with laggy connection to begin with.